# Getting to PyTesseract to work on cropped images of digits - unable to get correct digits

Tags: image-processing, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I am trying read digits from the face of a six sided die. It is a cropped image of just the face of the die. However, despite using many different configurations for `image_to_string` function I mostly get no result or a bunch of rubbish letters. These are some of the configurations I have tried:

```
    custom_config = '--oem 3 --psm 6 outputbase digits' 
    custom_config1 = '--psm 13 --oem 3 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789'
    custom_config2 = '--psm '
    custom_config3 = '-l eng --oem 3 --psm 12'
    custom_config4 = '--oem 1 --psm 9'
```

And here is an example of some of the images I am trying it on:

[Die showing 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdEJQ.jpg)

[Die showing 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4FTB.jpg)

[Die showing 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmys7.jpg)

[Die showing 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhZXp.jpg)

[Die showing 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KyDz5.jpg)

[Die showing 6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9y1p.jpg)

Not sure what other configuration I could use to successfully recognize the digits in the image. I thought this should be fairly simple, but apparently not as none of the configurations I have tried so far have worked. Can someone please try it on their own machine, and find a configuration that works? Or some guidelines on what to do next.

Comment: Are you able to find the four corners of the bright face ? If yes, you can invert the affine transformation (or the homography, but that makes little difference).

Comment: @YvesDaoust thank you. What do you mean by inverting the affine transformation, and how does this help?

Comment: It helps by solving your problem. But you did not answer.

Comment: @YvesDaoust sorry I completely forgot that part. I think I should be able to, as I able to draw contours, I should be able to find the corners of the contours

Comment: Then you can "morph" the quadrilateral back to an axis-aligned square.

Comment: @YvesDaoust yes of the bright face. How would I morph the back to an axis aligned square - does this help by getting the face in an upright position?

Comment: Do you understand "back to an axis-aligned square" ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust I think so. My understanding of that statement is that we rotate that the square (which represents the face of the die) so that is it is aligned with the x-axis, thereby making it easier for Tesseract to do its work

Comment: You also need to restore the right angle.  https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d61/tutorial_warp_affine.html

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Tesseract is not the right choice for your problem. It can't handle rotated text. Even if you use the OSD, your characters count should be +50 chars, and the rotation must be in 90, 180, 270 degrees. This is not stated in the documentation but It has been +2 years since I started using it intensively. I would suggest that you try PaddleOCR and if the rotation is known, rotate your dice image first.

Comment: I'm curiously waiting for your feedback after using PaddleOCR. :)

Comment: thank you so much for your comment. I have a few questions: what is OSD ? And furthermore, what if I rotate the image into the right orientation ? Is that something that can be done ? I figured out that in an upright orientation it works perfectly. Would this work, or would I still have to rely on PaddleOCR? I also wish it was clear that Tesseract doesn't work on rotated images, or maybe I was too blind to notice!

Comment: OSD is Orientation and Script detection in Tesseract. It's used to get the rotation angle of the text in an image. If your image rotation becomes in 0 degrees, Tesseract will be able to read it. So, it you can have the text in the right rotation, you don't have to use PaddleOCR. It's not stated in the documentation that it doesn't work because if you have blocks of text, the OSD may solve the problem. However, in your case you only have one digit, so this is not applicable to you.